# Mean distance between two points in a square polar coordinates conversion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, average

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4VqXRRXi68&t=337s), around the 5:20 mark, YouTuber MindYourDecisions converts the double integral from rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates so as to make the evaluation easier.

However, I fail to see how he managed to get the limits on the radius as $0$ and $\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$. Since the length of the adjacent side is always $1$, shouldn't the limits be $1\leq r \leq \sec\theta$?

The same result is obtained in [this](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath324/kmath324.htm) article. Thanks for any input. Sorry that I'm not seeing this.

Comment: The lower limit **of the radius** is 0, not 1. You are integrating from the origin ($r=0$) out to the vertical line $r=\sec\theta$, not from a circle of radius $1$ ($r=1$) out to the line.

Comment: Maybe I was confused on what the radius is in this scenario. You're saying he just means the line segment between the origin and any point in the lower half-triangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a vertical line we have the equation

$$ x=1 $$

But in polar coordinates $x=r \cos(\theta)$. Our equation becomes

$$ r \cos(\theta)=1 $$

$$ r = 1 / \cos(\theta)$$

The integration region includes the origin. The radius of the origin is $0$. $r$ is also nonnegative. Therefore the smallest value of $r$ is $0$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "If any part of the square includes the origin...". The line segment from the origin to the midpoint of the hypotenuse of the triangle inscribed in the square should surely have a nonzero radius, no?

Comment: The integration is over all $(x,y)$ points in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. Note that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Since $(0,0)$ is a point in your 2D integration region you will have $r=0$ for that point.

Comment: The integration is over all radii and angles which give points interior to the square.

Comment: The radius for the $\textit{point}$ $(0,0)$ is $0$, sure. But the line "if any part..." doesn't seem to fit. My thinking is that there are parts of the square that include the origin that are not the origin themselves.

Comment: The phrasing is bad. I will change it to be more clear.

Comment: The rest of your answer made complete sense though.

Comment: Thank you for your input!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I typed the answer out on a cell phone, and didn't choose my language carefully.